# Can sips -g capture image data on Photoshop .psb files over 4.5 GB?

Tags: macos, shell-script, adobe-photoshop, image-processing

When using the command sips -g profile on a .psb over 4.5GB, it returns nil. The same is true for -g bitsPerSample and -g space, though -g dpiWidth is able to capture data.

All these commands work as expected when the file is less than 4.5GB. I also noticed the profile (and other info) isn't displayed in the Finder preview window for images over 4.5GB. There appear to be no issues with the .psb itself and resaving it does not help.

Is there a size limitation with sips -g?

Comment: Have you try to open a image in PS, add on top layer with pure white, save and test again?

Comment: Adding the white layer did not help. However, after testing, I believe the issue is related to the Photoshop Format Options... it appears if "Maximize Compatibility" is checked when the .psb is saved, `sips -g all` will only report some of the image characteristics if the file is > 4.5GB, but if that is unchecked, it will report on all of them. Must be a backwards compatibility issue with Photoshop?

Comment: add this as answer and after day or two accept it :)

Comment: ..I responded too fast... the Maximize Compatibility wasn't the answer... turns out the reason that worked is because it dropped my 4.5GB file down to 4.3GB. That smaller size (<4.5GB) is what allowed it to work. If Max Compatibility is unchecked on a file over 4.5 GB, it still has the problem.

Comment: In such case maybe you can report a bug for this software.

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov. I reported it on the Apple and Adobe side. Appears `mdls` also has the same limitation, though `exiftool` seems to work, albeit having to install, which isn't ideal. The Adobe community says SIPS doesn't officially support PSB, which is likely the reason for the issue. Just odd it would work up until 4.5GB. Would think that info would be in the same place regardless.

Comment: I ended up switching over to ExifTool to get this to work.